# Restore a replace()

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm wondering on how to get back the original word or letter after i've used replace().

```js
function myReplace() {
  var str = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace("O", "!").replace("E", "#")
    .replace("T", "%").replace("N", "&");
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="test"> Olof Erik Thomas Niklas </p> 
<button onclick="myReplace()"> Try it </button>
```

Now when i press the button, the letters O,E,T and N changes as i want. But now i want them to go back to their original state. Anyone got any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... you could just store the original string in a variable prior to manipulating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way in this case is to simply save the original state of the text and then revert back to it.

```js
function myReplace() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("test");
  var str = ele.innerHTML;
  ele.setAttribute('data-orig', str);
  var res = str.replace("O", "!").replace("E", "#")
    .replace("T", "%").replace("N", "&");
  ele.innerHTML = res;
}

function myRestore() {
  var ele = document.getElementById("test");
  var str = ele.getAttribute('data-orig');
  ele.innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<p id="test"> Olof Erik Thomas Niklas </p> 
<button onclick="myReplace()"> Replace it </button>
<button onclick="myRestore()"> Restore it </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just access the `str` variable? Or create a variable to store the original value..

Answer (score 0):

Replacing characters is a non-reversible action. If your string contained an exclamation mark `!` before you did the first `replace()` then there is no way to distinguish it from the newly added exclamation marks.

In your case, there are no replaced characters in your input string. Therefore you can just swap the parameters.

```
str.replace("O", "!").replace("!", "O") === str
```